# Chrome Extension web api return json value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-chrome

I am very new to java script(just 2 days) and trying to build a chrome extension, and process the selected text on the page, then combine that into url, make the get request, value return will be in json format. then output the value in the extension or a balloon on top of the search value. (balloon is optional and for later stage)

however, I couldn't get it right, the popup doesn't return any values.

I tried different combinations from all the different methods online but in vain. Hope someone get point me which part went wrong. Thanks !

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "CP",
  "description": "CPP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus","tabs","https://xxx.xxx.com/*"],
  "browser_action":{
  "default_title":"Check CPP",
  "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
    "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "icons": {"128": "icon.png"},
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
  sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else
  sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response){
  sendServiceRequest(response.data);
  });
});

function getXHR(selectedText){
var urls = "https://xxx.xxx"+ selectedText; 
chrome.tabs.create({url: urls});
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', urls,true);
req.onload= processCP;
req.send();
}

function processCP;
{
    var resp = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
}
```